# Get started with pystache

Tags: python

This is really a newbie question, but I don't know how to search answers for this. I want to use pystache, and I am able to execute the .py file to print out some rendered output from .mustache file. but how exactly do I convert this into .html file? Specifically, how to put it on the server so that the browser would direct to the .html file like index.html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pystache is a template library **not** http server! If you want make webapp try to use ready-made webframeworks like Django or Pyramid.

Comment: if I have multiple similar htmls, wouldn't it be convenient to use those template to write them?

Comment: Django do have its own template engine, so it's really better way to port you html-templates into django.